# socketio.AsyncClient and proxy settings

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, aiohttp, http-proxy

I'm try to use python socket.io async client with http proxy, docs [say](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#socketio.AsyncClient) that i have to pass an initialized HTTP session object in http_session parameter, but I can't figure out how to do it, because aiohttp.ClientSession does not have such a parameter.

I used example

```py
import asyncio
import socketio
from aiohttp_proxy import ProxyConnector

connector = ProxyConnector.from_url('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)

sio = socketio.AsyncClient(logger=True, engineio_logger=True, http_session=session)

@sio.event
async def connect():
    print('connected to server')

@sio.event
async def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

@sio.event
def hello(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

async def start_server():
    await sio.connect('http://localhost:5000', auth={'token': 'my-token'})
    await sio.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start_server())
```

I've got RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task, apparently i have to initialize the object in the async function, but it’s not clear how to do this using an example.
Thanks for advice!